# textarea offset when two different textareas are possible at the same location using an EventListener

Tags: javascript, html, django, textarea

I have an event listener which will show a textarea for writing a message depending on a the subject line selected. The code works but the second textarea is indented for some reason.

The HTML code is:

```
<td>Message</td>
<td><textarea id="area1" cols="80" rows="6"
    onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';"
    name="area1">Please type your message here</textarea>
</td>
<td><textarea readonly id="area2" cols="80" rows="6" hidden
    name="area2">Some text here</textarea>
</td>
```

The javascript code is then:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('subject').addEventListener('change', function () {
        if (this.value == 'Subject1') {
            document.getElementById('area1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('area2').style.display = 'block'

        } else {
            document.getElementById('area1').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('area2').style.display = 'none'
        }
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: because you are hiding the input, not hiding the table cell. So you have an empty cell before the second.

Comment: Apologies I am used to Python and have recently started doing HTML and Javascript bits as part of a Django system, how would I change is so the table cell is being hidden?

Comment: @j.t.2.4.6 Just debugging help: If you right click on an element there's an option `inspect element`, it will open the Developer Console and below the DOM selector you can view all the CSS for that object. There's also a little box that shows padding/width/etc, which I find very helpful. This will help you with this and similar issues!- You can also open the Dev Console with F12!

Comment: Just put the textarea in the same cell as the other. I am hoping you are not using a table for layout. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by @epascarello

```
<td>Message</td>
<td><textarea id="area1" cols="80" rows="6"
    onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';"
    name="area1">Please type your message here</textarea>
    textarea readonly id="area2" cols="80" rows="6" hidden
    name="area2">Some text here</textarea>
</td>
```